# Haskell expression validation on tuple

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

is this expression valid on Haskell ?

```
(1,2,\_ ->3 )
```

I think it's valid but it gives an error when try it on GHCI prelude:

```
<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Show (t1 -> t))
      arising from a use of `print' at <interactive>:1:0-12
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (t1 -> t))
    In the expression: print it
    In a 'do' expression: print it
```

Comment: What error do you get? Is it about a missing Show instance? Remember that functions don't implement Show, so you can't print them to the screen, and this tuple contains a function in it.

Comment: Also, I would recommend just using the syntax `\_ -> 3`, particularly here on stackoverflow. It allows others to directly copy and paste your code, and haskell by default only uses ASCII, you have to turn in unicode support with the extension `UnicodeSyntax`

Comment: Yes it's about show it says no instance for show arising from use of print

Comment: That tuple is valid, you just can't print it to the screen. Try assigning it to a name using let, then asking for its type using `:type` in GHCi.

Comment: @AhmedFayed Please [edit] in the error you get. See [ask], more specifically [help/on-topic] and even more specifically the Verifiable part of [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

That expression is indeed valid. If the error you get is about not having any instance of `Show (t0 -> a0)`,  you could simply define a "dummy" one:

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> instance Show (a -> b) where
Prelude|     show f = ”fun”
Prelude|
Prelude> (1,2,\_ -> 3)
(1,2,fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
Prelude> let x = (1, 2, \_ -> 3)
Prelude> :print x
x = (_t1::forall t. (Integer, Integer, t -> Integer))
Prelude> let fst3 (x, y, z) = x
Prelude> let snd3 (x, y, z) = y
Prelude> let thrd (x, y, z) = z
Prelude> let f = fst3 x
Prelude> :print f
f = (_t2::Integer)
Prelude> let s = snd3 x
Prelude> :print s
s = (_t3::Integer)
Prelude> let t = thrd x
Prelude> :print t
t = (_t4::forall t. t -> Integer)
Prelude> :print x
x = (_t5::forall t. (Integer, Integer, t -> Integer))
Prelude> f
1
Prelude> :print x
x = (,,) 1 2 (_t6::t -> Integer)
Prelude> s
2
Prelude> :print x
x = (,,) 1 2 (_t7::t -> Integer)
Prelude> t "foo"
3
Prelude> :print x
x = (,,) 1 2 (_t8::t -> Integer)
```